# Improving performance of mapping standardized values with non equi joins - LIKE operator

Tags: performance, db2, db2-luw, query-performance

I have a large-ish data warehouse staging table (~2.5 million rows) that is using a mapping table to standardize a text column. I have an update statement that works perfectly, but has terrible performance, and would like some recommendations on modifications to the statement and/or alternate strategies for standardizing the data.

The source text can contain anything, and I'm basically looking for keywords in the strings. Because of the nature of the data, a longer string is more specific and therefore correct, so I want to get the longest mapping value found for each given row in the staging table.

Source data (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE STAGINGTABLE (TextColumn VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO STAGINGTABLE VALUES ('This entry has a full foo bar entry');
INSERT INTO STAGINGTABLE VALUES ('Today was a foo day');
INSERT INTO STAGINGTABLE VALUES ('Only found bar data');
INSERT INTO STAGINGTABLE VALUES ('Blah blah blah');

CREATE TABLE MAPPING (SourceMap VARCHAR(100), TargetMap VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO MAPPING VALUES ('%FOO BAR%', 'Foo Bar');
INSERT INTO MAPPING VALUES ('%FOO%', 'Foo');
INSERT INTO MAPPING VALUES ('%BAR%', 'Bar');
INSERT INTO MAPPING VALUES ('%%', 'Unknown');
```

Update statement:

```
UPDATE STAGINGTABLE
SET TextColumn = (
    SELECT TargetMap
    FROM (
        SELECT TargetMap
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TextColumn
            ORDER BY LEN(SourceMap) DESC) AS ROWNUM
        FROM STAGINGTABLE
        INNER JOIN MAPPING
            ON UPPER(TextColumn) LIKE SourceMap
        WHERE TextColumn IS NOT NULL
    ) AS STG_MAP
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
);
```

Final values in staging table after mapping:

```
Foo Bar
Foo
Bar
Unknown
```

Edit: the TextColumn and SourceMap columns do have non-clustered indexes.

Comment: Try 1) `MERGE`, 2) a functional index on `UPPER(TextColumn)` if your Db2 version supports it, 3) materializing `LEN(SourceMap)` as a computed column.

Comment: @mustaccio MERGE was my first iteration of the statement, and I had already gained some performance by only doing an UPDATE. #2 sounds interesting, I hadn't heard of that feature before and will investigate. I believe we're on 10.5 so it should be supported. After that I'll also try #3. Thanks!

Comment: Then try 4) `MERGE` after the others.

Comment: By the way, I hope that's not your real update statement, as it's uncorrelated and won't run in its current form. And it's probably `LENGTH(SourceMap)`.

Comment: An index `on mapping (sourcemap, length(sourcemap) desc, targetmap)` might also help.

Comment: Have you considered trying the full text engine feature? https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/dm-0810shettar/#search-with-db2-text-search

Comment: Is the mapping static, or are new entries added on a regular basis?

Comment: @SQLRaptor I considered it, but unfortunately it's an enterprise environment that doesn't have it, and I'm just 1 lonely developer with no chance of getting it added.

Comment: @Lennart It's mostly static, but there is a chance of users entering something goofy somehow, so there may be new mappings once or twice a year.

Comment: @mustaccio No, it's not the real update statement. I also work in SQL Server, hence the LEN function and not LENGTH when I was writing the example off memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's comments and suggestions, I tried all of the ideas @mustaccio posted, but in the end the fastest strategy was to abandon the mapping table altogether, and just go with a big ugly CASE statement to handle all of the situations, and insert that into another staging table. Execution time dropped to only a few seconds, and I can't argue with that. The situations to handle are mostly static, so if I have to re-deploy a SSIS package once or twice a year to add new situations if they come up, so be it.

Final example insert statement (not exact, just going off memory):

```
INSERT INTO STAGINGTABLE_TWO (TextColumn) 
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN TextColumn LIKE '%FOO BAR%' THEN 'Foo Bar'
    WHEN TextColumn LIKE '%FOO%' THEN 'Foo'
    WHEN TextColumn LIKE '%BAR%' THEN 'Bar'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
  END
FROM STAGINGTABLE;
```